# HTML5 Doctype screws up DIV heights?

Tags: css, html

When rendering a page in Chrome, Safari, or Firefox on Mac, if I use the HTML5 doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and put an image inside a div, the div is rendered consistently 4 pixels too tall. If I use the older doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

The divs are rendered correctly, which is the same height as the image inside it. This is using the exact same HTML and CSS code. The only thing that changes is the doctype and an extra 4 pixels show up. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You should take a look at html5reset.org

Answer (score 10):

http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

`<!DOCTYPE html>` = Standards Mode - http://jsbin.com/ogacor

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` = Almost Standards Mode - http://jsbin.com/ogacor/2

To fix it, add `display: block` or `vertical-align: top` (or `bottom`) to the `img`.

The reason this happens in the first place is that `img`s are by default `inline` elements, and have a default `vertical-align` of `baseline`. The baseline does not touch the bottom of the containing element - the gap is the distance between the two.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko%27s_Almost_Standards_Mode
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Images%2c_Tables%2c_and_Mysterious_Gaps

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 specifies that the whitespace within elements should be rendered. Therefor you get the 4px extra, if you set font-size to those elements to 0 for example, the space will dissapear.

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with HTML5. It's "Standards mode" vs "not". `font-size: 0` does work to fix it, but it's not the usual fix.

Comment: This is not true, I'm not sure why it got 3 votes. The answer below is valid.